# Why do I only get this error on one of my computers and not the rest?

Tags: errors, sublime-text, latextools

I was writing a chemistry lab report earlier and when I went to compile , I got an error I have never seen before. The error is in part of the template I use for all my papers, so I tried compiling the template on it's own and I still got the error. I had just used the same exact template yesterday on my other PC and it compiled correctly, so I tested it on that PC later when I got home, and it worked completely fine. Some how my template compiles on one computer and not the other.

Both of my PCs are running Sublime Text 3 Build 3083 with the most recent build of the "LaTeX Tools" plugin.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=0.1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\setlength {\parindent} {1cm}

\doublespacing
\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{.\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \fancyhead{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{Name\\Date\\Class}
  \fancyhead[R]{}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin {center}

 Title \\

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here is the error it produces:

```
  File "C:\Users\wes1099\Dropbox\Documents\2015-2016\template1.tex", line 1
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Looks like you have an invisible character there you shouldn't. Check that your TeX installations are current - not the editors, that's just the editor and irrelevant, but your actually installation of TeX. And check you are using the same settings for encodings on both machines.

Comment: The error seems to come from SublimeText (TeX never issues error messages starting with `SyntaxError`). Can you try compiling the same document on the same machine, but from the command line or from another editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've somehow got your **Build System** set to Python instead of LaTeX. You can change this from the menu under **Tools** > **Build System** which can be set to either **LaTeX** or **Automatic**.

A likely culprit for this is the Anaconda plugin for SublimeText which seems to like to automatically change your builder to a Python builder. You can disable that behaviour through the settings for the Anaconda plugin itself.